# Do I still need to use Facebook user access tokens to post to Facebook pages?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-page

I've **created** and **stored permanent facebook page access tokens**. Must I still use a user access token each time I want to post to a fb page feed, or can I use only the page access token?

Here is command I'm using to setup the post now:

```
$page_post = (new FacebookRequest( **$session**, 'POST', '/'. $page_id .'/feed', array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'name' => 'Randy Steel',
        'link' => 'http://www.LIPSapp.com/',
        'caption' => 'Example text',
        'message' => 'This is my link!',
) ));
```

Where **$session holds the user access token** and $access_token holds the permanent page access token.

**If**, because I have the perm page access token, I can **skip** getting/updating the 
**user access token** (60 days at best), how would the above command change? 
**What** would the **value of $session** need to be, or can that parameter be omitted?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

With Facebook's new update like 2 years ago, pages acts like normal profile pages. So you only need access tokens of page not administrator's. Access tokens can be changed overtime or can be expired so it's best you to store administrators access token just in cas the access key losts its validity.

Comment: Thanks em, but how would the command change? Since session is loaded with the user access token and I don't need it, how do I change the command? I'm getting an error when I leave $session out or sest it to ''

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to post "as Page", you can use the stored Page Token - in fact, you HAVE to use the Page Token to post "as Page". You only need the User Token once, for getting an Extended Page Token.

I would not even use the PHP SDK for that, basic CURL calls are good enough. A small example of using CURL with the Facebook API can be found here: http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Comment: Thanks luschn. I'll go read up on it. But since I have this working, I was really looking for how would the command change now that it appears I do not need the admin (user) access token?

Comment: take a look at the link i posted. you should not use the php sdk for those easy things.